# How can I install new fonts to jasper reports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm getting "Could not load the following font" error. I installed this font in jasper reports. What am I missing so I'm taking this error ?

Comment: You may have solved it by now. But for the record: just installing the font in Jasper reports is not enough. If you want to use the font in the Java project, you should also export the font and add it as a library to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your IDE terminal:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./font/fonts.jar -DgroupId=ttf -DartifactId=fonts -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```